# React Js : Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I was trying to create a functionality which will have -

2 textboxes - 1 for key , 1 for value

Array which will hold value with textboxes when button will be clicked.

Display array in a list

For this I created component in React Js -

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function  HookArray() {
    const[lKey,setKey]=useState('');
    const[lValue,setValue]=useState('');
    const[lKeyValue,setArray]=useState({id:'',value:''});

    const addItem=()=>{
            setArray(...lKeyValue,{lKey,lValue})
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <div id="divArrayList">
                
                <ul>
                    {
                        
                        lKeyValue.map(x=>
                            (
                             <li key={x.id} value={x.value}></li>   
                            ))
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
            <input id="txtKey" type="text"  onChange={setKey(x=>x.target.value)} ></input>
            <br></br>
            <input id="txtValue" type="text"  onChange={setValue(x=>x.target.value)}></input>
            <br></br>
            <input type="button" onClick="addItem();">Add</input>
        </div>
    )
}
export default HookArray;
```

But this is throwing error at run time -

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are invoking the callbacks immediately. They need to be defined in such away to be called later when changed/clicked. Pass the `onChange` event object so the value can be accessed. For the button you can simply attach the handler since the event is irrelevant.

```
 <input
   id="txtKey"
   type="text"
   onChange={e => setKey(e.target.value)} // callback accepts event object
 />
 ...
 <input
   id="txtValue"
   type="text"
   onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} // callback accepts event object
 />
 ...
 <input
   type="button"
   onClick={addItem} // direct attach addItem callback
 >
   Add
 </input>
```